# When I click back arrow made on title bar instead of going to previous panel it goes out of the application?

Tags: android, xml

.When I click "back arrow"on the titlebar it has to move back from TeacherAdminPanel to StudentAdminPanel but it goes out of system,  I have tried a lot but cannot solve this, as myself introduce as a beginner for android.Please help me!

```
 <activity
  android:name=".teacher_admin_panel"
  android:label="TeacherAdminPanel"
  android:parentActivityName=".Student_AdminPanel"/>
 //This is the code for Androidmanifest.xml


  getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
 //This is the code for backarrow in the TeacherAdminPanel
```

Comment: try following the android docs for providing up navigation : https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral#java

Comment: I am unable to solve this, Mainfest code and the java  Code where I want to generate back arrow inorder to move forward activity is presented in the below section because I cannot able to paste all the codes in comments so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you shift activity, do you finish the activity you are going from? If you finish the activity you remove it from the activity backstack, hence you have nothing to go back to, so the app will close.

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack

Comment: How can I implement back-stack in this code,can you kindly help me?

Comment: The way to get a activity added to the task backstack, can be done if you chance activities with intents. Can you show me your code used for changing activity?

Comment: Intent detailActivity = new Intent(this,DashBoardActivity.class);
        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
        stackBuilder.addNextIntentWithParentStack(detailActivity);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

Comment: Doesnt it work if you just change activity without trying to add it to the backstack manually?

Comment: I am unable to solve this, Mainfest code and the java  Code where I want to generate back arrow inorder to move forward activity is presented in the below section because I cannot able to paste all the codes in comments so.